# which statement is true for $f(x)$ at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f(x)$ has continuous second derivative in some neighbourhood of $x=0$ and $\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{f''\left(x\right)}{e^x-1}=1.$ Then $f(x)$ at $x=0$ is

1. There are extreme values
2. No extreme values
3. No turning points
4. There is an inflection point.

**My attempt**

Since Let $f(x)$ has continuous second derivative in some neighbourhood of $x=0.$ So, by the property of continuity,$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{f''\left(x\right)}{e^x-1}=1>0\implies $ $\frac{f''\left(x\right)}{e^x-1}>0$ for some neighborhood of $0$. Let that neighbourhood is $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. $x>0 \implies e^x-1>0 \implies f''(x)>0$ and $x<0 \implies e^x-1<0 \implies f''(x)<0.$ By intermediate theorem, $f''(0)=0.$ So, it is an inflection point. Is my logic correct?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see that $f''(0) = 0$ is to consider the multiplication property of limits:

$$\begin{align*}
f''(x) &= \frac{f''(x)}{e^x-1} \cdot (e^x-1)&&(x\ne 0)\\
\lim_{x\to 0} f''(x)
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f''(x)}{e^x-1} \cdot \lim_{x\to 0}(e^x-1)\\
&= 1\cdot 0 = 0
\end{align*}$$

In a neighbourhood of $0$, the sign of $f''(x)$ follows the sign of $e^x-1$.

And at $x=0$, since $f''$ is continuous,

$$f''(0) = \lim_{x\to0}f''(x) = 0$$